# Cite a developed version of an algorithm (citation chain)?

Tags: publications, citations

My work is based on `algorithm A` that is actually a developed version of `algorithm B`. When I cite `algorithm A`, should I also cite `algorithm B`?

Due to the conference page limit, I prefer not to cite `algorithm B`, as `A` has already cited `B` and I do have cited `A`. Does my this "citation chain" work?

Another dilemma to me is when `algorithm C` incorporates *(**not** develops)* `algorithm B`, given the fact that I have to cite `C` anyway and actually I have used `algorithm B`, can I choose to only cite `C` without `B`? *(again, to save space)*

Comment: There are better ways to save space.

Answer (score 6):

Space savings aside, your choice in this must be guided by two factors: **help the readers understand** what your work is built upon, and **acknowledge scientific contributions** of your predecessors.

With those principles in mind, I would say the choice depends on the relationship between A and B, and whether either (or both) are well-known. Let's take two simple cases to illustrate:

- if algorithm B is world-famous, and algorithm A is a not-so-well-known extension (e.g., because it is specially optimized for a specific type of data): you will have to cite both, as you cannot assume that all readers are familiar with algorithm A.

  > Herein we highlight an extension of the Abersmith algorithm,[ref A] which is itself based on the Borodin sort algorithm with specific improvements for the handling of *p*-adic input.
- if algorithm A is very well known in your field, and algorithm B was an earlier algorithm that was almost completely superseded by A and little used nowadays (except for historical considerations): it is not useful to cite B.

Comment: So your case 1 is my case. My work is a direct application of algorithm A that is based on world-famous B. I will definitely have to cite A, since I directly adopt the method with some minor modifications. I also must cite the world-famous B?

Comment: Yes, you have to give (even in a few words) the reader a short introduction to A, which means you have to introduce B (and cite it)